# Link totals from other worksheets to a Summary Page by referencing the last row in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I am constructing a macro to take a data dump, sort on certain criteria, move each new data set to a new worksheet, sum the data, and then bring those totals over to the Summary Page.

I built the entire code, except I cannot get my Summary Page to link to the worksheets correctly. Originally, I linked to a specific cell using something like:

```
Range("G3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='CR RESIDUALS - 1 to 15'!R[878]C[5]"
```

The total will not always be in that same cell. It will be in column (L), but it could be 100 rows or even 1000. I tried using variations of "& lastrow".

I have a total of 12 tabs. How could I link my worksheets back to the Summary Page, while taking into account the varying row count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without VBA, In G3 put the following formula:

```
=INDEX('CR RESIDUALS - 1 to 15'!L:L,MATCH(1e99,'CR RESIDUALS - 1 to 15'!L:L))
```

This will always return the last cell that has a numeric value in column L of sheet CR RESIDUALS - 1 to 15.  The reference will change automatically with the number of rows.  No need to rerun the vba.

If you want to assign the formula in vba then:

```
Range("G3").Formula = "=INDEX('CR RESIDUALS - 1 to 15'!L:L,MATCH(1e99,'CR RESIDUALS - 1 to 15'!L:L))"
```

Comment: Thank you Scott for getting back to me! Do you know if I can use this code with VBA? Due to the type of report, I'm trying to stick to VBA. I tried to use the code in VBA, but it changed the formula while running.

In code:
 Range("G3").Select
 ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('CR RESIDUALS - 1 to 15'!L:L,MATCH(1e99,'CR RESIDUALS - 1 to 15'!L:L))"

After Macro Ran, in cell G3:
=INDEX('CR RESIDUALS - 1 to 15'!L:(L),MATCH(1e99,'CR RESIDUALS - 1 to 15'!L:(L)))

If I edit the formula after it is ran, it works perfectly. Is there a way to keep the code from changing when the Macro runs?

Comment: @H.Martin see edit.  If this is what you use please mark it as correct, by hitting the green check mark by the answer.  Only the Original Poster can select the correct answer.

Comment: @H.Martin but if you are going to continually assign a new formula every time the data changes then Scott Holtzman's answer is better.

Comment: The formula will always be the same. Thank you and will do!!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the formula like this. You can make the changes necessary for each page.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("CR RESIDUALS - 1 to 15")

Dim lRow as Long
lRow = ws.Range("L" & ws.Rows).End(xlup).Row

Dim wsSummary as Worksheet
Set wsSummary = Worksheets("Summary")

wsSummary.Range("G3").Formula = "='CR RESIDUALS - 1 to 15'!L" & lRow
```